# What happens to the Openlayer map instance after the DOM element is removed?

Tags: openlayers

I have an application contains multiple Openlayer map instances.

Each map instance lives in a temporary DOM element which is created in the runtime, and the DOM node will be destroyed after the page is closed.

My question is: what happens to the underlying OL map object after the targeted DOM element is destroyed? When I re-open the page, can I still use this same OL object which was created before and re-target the DOM location to get it rendered?

I tired the re-target approach but it appears the Map would just not show up from the canvas, does that mean we have to construct a new map instance every time we load the page?

Comment: If you remove OL map's DEM element, you have to recreate map from scratch.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like that's the case! @TomazicM